# Gstreamer tsdemux support of Synchronous KLV

Tags: gstreamer, klvdata

I am using the ubuntu apt package version of `gstreamer` which is v1.16.3  This version `tsdemux` plugin does not support `Synchronous KLV`.

I found 5-year old PRs about this, but I don't see their edits in the tsdemux.c source for this version branch or main:

PRs:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/434,
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/642

source:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/blob/discontinued-for-monorepo/gst/mpegtsdemux/tsdemux.c?ref_type=heads

Is there a tsdemux plugin version available that supports Sychronous KLV (public or private)?  If not, I will work on it.  But, I hope it's out there somewhere.